# NodeJS/Express: Reading header, which was set previously, results undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set some header informations (for authentication).
But as I cannot read the header, I tried to set, I must do something wrong:

```
const app = express()
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('x-access-token', 'secret')
  console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']) // returns undefined
  next()
})

app.get('/test',
  (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('x-access-token', 'secret')
    console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']) // returns undefined
    res.send('Running...')
  }
)
```

Comment: Response headers & request headers have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: Oh... So there seems to be a big misunderstanding from my side :-( I'm trying to use token in my express api and I thought this is how I have to use it...

Comment: That depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmmm right now I'm running the express/node server with apollo and graphql (connected with a mongoDB). Now I would like to add JWT for authentication. So only logged users should get access to the api (calling queries or mutations).

Comment: You are reading the header correctly from what I can see. You are probably receiving requests without that header field set if it's undefined. You can test with Postman. You can remove the res.setHeader stuff.

Comment: You generally use JWT when you have a separate front end application making ajax requests to your API.  If you are doing this, then set the header in the front end application, and read them in your application. If you are connecting to your server directly through the browser consider using sessions.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding how headers work.  You need to learn more about how HTTP & security features work before you can write secure authentication code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some middleware to set a token value that you can use later on in the processing chain, then just set it as a custom property on the `req` object and access it from there.  There is no reason to try to jam something into the headers and then parse it out again later.

In addition, `res.setHeader()` sets a response header, not a request header.  Those are two very different things that literally have nothing to do with one another.

So, you could just set a a `req.myToken` property in the middleware and then use that later in the processing chain:

```
const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.myToken = 'secret';
  console.log(req.myToken);
  next();
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    // get token set by middleware
    let token = req.myToken;
    // set token as a response header so the client can see it
    res.setHeader('x-access-token', token);
    res.send('Running...')
});
```